# HTML inside bootstrap 5 tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

Following the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#examples), I need to display some HTML inside a bootstrap 5 tooltip.

However, copy pasta from the doc does not give the expected output.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>">
                                    Tooltip with HTML
                                  </button>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndxs0hrm/1/).

Instead of displaying parsed HTML, HTML is parse as text.

How can I display content as HTML instead of text ?

Comment: You are using Bootstrap5, yet you are working off of the documentation for version 4. The attribute enabling HTML content needs to be `data-bs-html="true"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [Bootstrap v5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#markup) you should use `data-bs-html="true"`.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" title="<em>Tooltip</em> <u>with</u> <b>HTML</b>">
  Tooltip with HTML
</button>
```

[Your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rsz0763a/).