# Inside Bootstrap 5 Tooltip not working properly

Tags: html, jquery, tooltip

I'm working with Bootstrap 5 Tooltip and showing the tooltip message inside the table icon like below example

[image: Showing tool tip]

To achieve this I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69042206/html-inside-bootstrap-5-tooltip) & [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tooltip&stacked=h) solutions and  written html and jQuery logic like below

html:

```
var OI = 1.222;
var Chg = 34.444;

 var tltp = `<i class="info-tooltp" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-original-title="<div class=strikeinfocontent><p><span>OI : </span><b>${OI}</b></p><p><span>OI Chg : </span><b>${Chg}</b></p></div>"></i>`

$(".strattabletodivtbody").append(tltp);
```

In the above, I'm appending the `tltp` to table body and it is appending successfully

Output is like below:

[image: Rows adding]

Entire table logic is like below example:

[image: table logic]

And jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Initialize tooltips
        var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
        var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
          return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
        })

)};
```

And another way I have tried to show the tooltip message using jQuery like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".info-tooltp").hover(function () {
            $(this).tooltip("show");
            //alert('hit');
        });

)};
```

Here I used the class name `.info-tooltp` to show the tooltip message but it is also not working properly because in my UI design I have a add button so if I click on the add button the same row should add to the table (my UI like below example) and the row is adding but the tooltip is not working.

[image: UI design]

In the above Image if I mouse hover on the `i` icon that related data should show.

Suggest me where I did the mistake and how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your dynamically created tooltip else it will not work because at the time of running this code `tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTr..` your tooltip was not present. For  solving this you can get the last tool tip added in your DOM and use `new bootstrap.Tooltip($(".strattabletodivtbody").find(".info-tooltp:last")[0])` this will initialize your tooltip.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("#add").click(function() {

  var random = $(".info-tooltp").length + 1;
  var OI = 1 + random;
  var Chg = 34 + random;

  var tltp = `<tr><td>Something${random}..</td><td><i class="info-tooltp fa fa-close" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-original-title="<div class=strikeinfocontent><p><span>OI : </span><b>${OI}</b></p><p><span>OI Chg : </span><b>${Chg}</b></p></div>"></i></td></tr>`

  $(".strattabletodivtbody").append(tltp);

  new bootstrap.Tooltip($(".strattabletodivtbody").find(".info-tooltp:last")[0]) // this will initialize your tool-tip

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<table class="strattabletodivtbody">
</table>


<button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
```

Comment: Hi @Swati ji thanks for your answer post and it is working fine now.